# How can i get the Querystring from URL?

Tags: php, url

Hi I have URl like below

```
http://word.dev.net/apps/website-management?affiliate=true
```

now I am using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` for getting current url. what I need to do to get the string `affiliate=true` alone?.. please help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for

```
$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]
```

You can find all (usually) predefined variables in PHP [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php).

What often helps is doing a `phpinfo()` that will list all environment and other variables that are currently set.

Answer (score 2):

That is called a GET variable, and you can acces it via the global variable

```
$_GET['affiliate']
```

So in your code you would do something like:

```
if(isset($_GET['affiliate']))
      /*do something with the var*/
```

or if you are really interested in just the string itself you can access it using the

```
$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]
```

global variable

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` with `parse_url` function in PHP (http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to get the url components.